# How to do dot product in a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, dot-product

I have a cell array (`C`) containing 5 matrices. Each matrix represents different set of vectors (i.e. Each matrix has two columns. One is x coordinate; the other is y coordinate. The row number varying depends on the number of vectors)

```
C{1} = [20x2 double];
C{2} = [23x2 double]; 
C{3} = [32x2 double] ...
```

In this case, there are 20 vectors in C{1}; 23 vectors in C{2} and so on. Is there any way (other than one or two for loop)to do the dot product for the two adjacent vectors for each matrix?

```
C{1} = [2,3; 1,2; 5,4; 8,3; ...]
```

calculate the dot product for [2,3]&[1,2] then [1,2]&[5,4] then [5,4]&[8,3] and so on.

So at the end, I would expect to get a cell array with 5 cells. Each cell is an [n-1,1] array (n is the length of the matrix).

```
dots = [5x1 cell]. 
dots{1} = [19x1 double]; 
dots{2} = [22x1 double];
dots{3} = [31x1 double] ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to compute the dot product between each coordinate (row) and the next coordinate (row).

```
dots = cellfun(@(x)dot(x(1:end-1,:), x(2:end, :), 2), C, 'uniform', 0)
```

**Explanation**

We grab the first rows to compare using `x(1:end-1,:)` and then want to perform the dot product with the *next* row `x(2:end,:)`. When performing the dot product, we want to specify that we want the dot product along the second dimension so we provide a `2` for the third input to `dot`.

```
dp = dot(C{1}(1:end-1,:), C{1}(2:end,:), 2);
```

We use `cellfun` to perform this on each cell array element.

**Example**

```
C = {rand(10,2), rand(20,2), rand(30,2), rand(40, 2), rand(50,2)};
dots = cellfun(@(x)dot(x(1:end-1,:), x(2:end, :), 2), C, 'uniform', 0)

    [9x1 double]   [19x1 double]   [29x1 double]   [39x1 double]   [49x1 double]
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will give me one dot product for each matrix and results in a nx1 vector (n is the length of the cell array). In my case, I would like to do the dot product for 4 elements at a time. Thus, if C{1} = [20x2 double], I would expect to get an [19x1 double] array.

Comment: @JameeLin Ok answer is updated to account for this. Hopefully it works as expected now.